# Por que o sistema operacional usa o SWAP quando ainda tem RAM

Tags: windows, sistema-operacional

Eu aprendi que a memória virtual (SWAP) só passava a ser usada quando a memória RAM tivesse alcançado sua **capacidade máxima** (ou quase). Mas, percebo que não é bem assim, segundo essa imagem que tirei do desempenho do meu computador:

[image: Desempenho do Sistema]

Por que isso acontece? Não estou desperdiçando minha memória RAM (8GB)? Que vantagem tem para o computador usar a virtual antes de preencher toda a física?

Answer (score 0):

Cada sistema operacional tem sua estratégia para usar swap. Se você tem mesmo memória sobrando, provavelmente o seu sistema está gravando partes da memória no swap mesmo sem precisar. Se houver uma necessidade urgente de memória, seja rápido liberar esta memória, pois já está "Swapada".

O consumo de RAM sempre vai tender a 100% mesmo com carga leve porque o sistema aproveita a sobra para cachear arquivos.

Há 15 ou 20 anos atrás os sistemas operacionais ainda estavam acertando a mão com estas coisas, e podia acontecer de um sistema ficar mais lento com swap do que sem, com memória sobrando. Aí tinha as pajelanças de usar swap do tamanho da RAM, swap com o dobro da RAM, etc. Hoje em dia não é mais relevante.